# How to set the profile picture on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, profile-picture

How do I set the profile picture on Stack Overflow?

I want to set my profile picture in my account, but I can't find a way to upload the picture.

Answer (score 4):

Now we can set profile picture :

1. picture linked from [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/)
2. directly upload from PC
3. when using your Facebook account to log in, changes to your profile picture are reflected on these sites automatically.

As @NidhishKrishnan suggested, in **step 3** it now shows interface for changing profile pic from above 2 options. 1st option was present from launching of stack-overflow. But 2nd option was given lately in 2nd week of Jan 2013.

See also [Announcing a new way to change your profile picture](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/?cb=1)

Answer (score 3):

**STEP 1:** go to your home page and click edit

**STEP 2:** now you can see a option for changing the picture at the left side

**STEP 3:** on clicking , it will redirect to http://en.gravatar.com/ where you have to create an account and upload your profile pic

Answer (score 1):

With StackOverflow's changes now you can set your picture directly from your profile page without going to Gravtar. Just hover your mouse pointer on your profile picture and you will see a link **Change Picture** and clicking on it you can directly upload picture!!